# Getting information through Servlet from running Java Thread

Tags: java, servlets

I have a little problem figuring this out the right way.

I have a Java application reading a log file continuously using threads. While that application is still reading the log file, a client should be able to query the current status (i.e. a certain key was found in the log file) through a java servlet.

My current issue is that I am having problems getting that status using the doGet-Method of the servlet. WHile running the thread is supposed to change a single boolean variable.

My question is:

How do I get the Log Reader Thread to start running when I deploy the Servlet on my Tomcat. In idle mode the Log Reader is listening for new files in a folder and starts to read them once they appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below link you can use SevletcontexListener

In SevletcontexListener you can start you logger

[Link](http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/what-is-listener-servletcontextlistener-example/)

```
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) 
    {
          System.out.println("ServletContextListener started"); 
         //start thread here
    }
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
     //stop thread here
}
```

Comment: Okay. So I have that ContextListener running. How does the listener run my thread though? Thanks for your help!

Comment: include your Thread  work in a separate class and instantiate that class in Listener.

Comment: you probably also want to shutdown the thread on `contextDestroyed`, otherwise the web server cannot undeploy or shutdown cleanly.

Comment: Okay this starts my Thread with the web service. Now I have the problem that my Tomcat does not startup as it is waiting for the thread to finish. What do I do here?

Answer (score 1):

> My current issue is that I am having problems getting that status using the doGet-Method of the servlet. WHile running the thread is supposed to change a single boolean variable.

That's probably because of concurrent update of non thread-safe boolean value. For more details on this topic you can read following tutorial on [Java Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)

> How do I get the Log Reader Thread to start running when I deploy the Servlet on my Tomcat. In idle mode the Log Reader is listening for new files in a folder and starts to read them once they appear?

Please refer to [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050186/tomcat-6-thread-pool-for-asynchronous-processing/11053152#11053152), where it is described how to start threads from `ServletContextListener` using `Executors`, which are high-level abstractions over threads.

Hope this helps...